# System settings: order of bluetooth devices in list

Tags: settings, bluetooth, usability

On Android 11, I noticed the list of "Previously connected devices" does not show the latest successfully connected device. That said, when I want to manually force a Bluetooth connection to a specific device, I always need to click on "See all" then browse and try to find the bluetooth device.

My list has around ~25 entries as today and is tedious to search. I would like to know if it's possible to have this list somehow sorted from the most recently connected to the older one.

Do you know any trick for doing that?

[image: Bluetooth settings]

Comment: This is quite an annoying little issue, as there are about six or seven devices that I connect to frequently, but they are scattered across the list, so I had to resort to extending their names with long strings of dots (like `Bathroom Echo Dot •••••••••••••••`), so they are easier to spot in the long list. Also, the order in the list that opens from the quick settings panel dropdown should at least put the currently connected devices on the top, so they can be quickly disconnected... 